Angular Dart project is not running
I am setting up angular dart in my machine and currently i am using dart version 2.19.0. All the steps are done and i created a new project in my visual studio code but when i am trying to run that new project using command webdev serve it's failing with below error:
#48     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
#49     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:123:13)
#50     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:193:5)
**[INFO] /C:/Users/prana/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/build_modules-4.0.6/lib/src/module_cache.dart:21:70: Error: The method 'toJson' isn't defined for th[INFO] /C:/Users/prana/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/build_modules-4.0.6/lib/src/module_cache.dart:24:66: Error: The method 'toJson' isn't defined for th[SEVERE] Failed to precompile build script .dart_tool/build/entrypoint/build.dart.
[SEVERE] This is likely caused by a misconfigured builder definition.
[SEVERE]
Unhandled exception:
Bad state: Unable to start build daemon.**
#0      _handleDaemonStartup.<anonymous closure> (package:build_daemon/client.dart:79:21)
#1      _runUserCode (dart:async/stream_pipe.dart:11:23)
#2      Stream.firstWhere.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/stream.dart:1704:9)
#3      _RootZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1581:10)
#4      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendDone.sendDone (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:392:13)

Can anyone tell me what i can do for this.
Below is my pubspec.yml file data:
environment:
  sdk: '>=2.10.0 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  ngdart: ^7.1.1
  ngcomponents: ^1.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  ngtest: ^4.1.1
  build_runner: ^2.2.0
  build_version: ^2.1.1
  build_test: ^2.1.5
  build_web_compilers: ^3.2.4
  lints: ^1.0.1
  test: ^1.21.0

